# Fast find an item in a List(of T) by aggregate property

Tags: vb.net, list, search

I have a list of objects that looks like this:

```
Public Class LineItem
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Weight As Int32
    Public Property Expression As String
End Class

Private _lineItems As New List(Of LineItem)
```

I randomly select one item as so:

```
Public Function SelectItem(ByVal name As String) As LineItem
    Dim items As List(Of LineItem) = CType(Rules.Where(Function(li As LineItem) li.Name = name.Remove("[", "]")).ToList, List(Of LineItem))
    Dim totalWeight As Int32 = items.Sum(Function(li As LineItem) li.Weight)

    If totalWeight > 0 Then
        Dim sum As Int32 = 0
        Dim index As Int32 = (BaseGrammar.Random.Next Mod totalWeight) + 1
        For Each item As LineItem In items
            sum += CInt(item.Weight)
            If sum >= index Then
                Return item
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

While this works fine for small lists, when the lists get large, obviously it is terribly inefficient.  Is there a structure or method that I'm missing that could make this more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you function is fine, but did you considered that you code goes through the loop 3 times .. first to take out characters, than find sum, and then capture the subset of items.  Maybe if you redo your code by removing initial Linq, you can make a regular loop in which you can fix Name property and sum up Weight.  That will cut your time by 33%

Comment: That's a good point.  I think I can probably cache the Name lists and total weights so when I recall this code it'll be much faster.

Comment: Just to update, I ended up moving to a single loop for the name lists and weights and cached them in a dictionary and the speed is now nearly instantaneous.  Thank you again.